# GPUで半精度（Half Precision）で計算できる NVIDIA Volta GPUs は NVIDIA Tesla V100 だけですか？

Tags: 深層学習, gpu

深層学習で計算速度を上げるために半精度（Half Precision）での計算を行いたいです．
この[論文](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.00187.pdf)の 4.1 によると， NVIDIA Volta GPUs というのが半精度での計算ができるようなのですが，具体的にどの種類のGPUが可能なのでしょうか．調べたところ， NVIDIA Tesla V100 がそれにあたるようなのですが，例えば GeForce GTX TITAN X や GeForce GTX 1080 Ti は半精度で計算できるますか？

Answer (score 0):

その[論文](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.00187.pdf)：

> NVIDIA Volta GPUs introduce Tensor Cores that enable efficient half precision floating point (FP) computations that are several times faster than full precision operations. (...) This can be mitigated by scaling values to fit into the FP16 range.

から確かに、Volta コアから導入された **FP16** というキーワードで示されるフィーチャーのようだということがわかります。

Volta コアの製品は、[wikipedia (en)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volta_(microarchitecture)) によると、

- Tesla V100
- Tesla V100S PCIe
- Titan V
- Titan V CEO Edition
- Quadro GV100

となっており、データセンター向けのもののようで、リリースは 2017-12。

後継は [Turing コア](https://www.nvidia.com/content/dam/en-zz/Solutions/design-visualization/technologies/turing-architecture/NVIDIA-Turing-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf)（現行の最新、リリースは 2018-09）で、こちらは全般に採用されているようです。

> **Turing Tensor Cores**
>   Turing GPUs include an enhanced version of the Tensor Cores first introduced in the Volta GV100 GPU. The Turing Tensor Core design adds INT8 and INT4 precision modes for inferencing workloads that can tolerate quantization. **FP16 is also fully supported** for workloads that require higher precision.

ということで、Volta 以降の Turing コアも含む新しい世代の GPU のものが FP16 をサポートしていることになると思います。[Turing の製品一覧（wikipedia (en)）](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_(microarchitecture)#Products_using_Turing)

> GeForce GTX TITAN X や GeForce GTX 1080 Ti

これらは Maxwell コアや Pascal コアなので、古くて駄目ですね。

Comment: FP16のスループットがFP32と同じだけでGTX 10X0世代でも演算自体は出来るようです https://www.slideshare.net/tomoaki0705/gpgpu-tomoakifp16

Comment: @zakki 情報ありがとうございます。ソフトウェア的な互換性はあるということですね。ただ質問者の「計算速度を上げるため」の FP16 の導入という意味では、Turing コア以降でないと意味が薄いような気もしますが。

Answer (score 0):

理論演算性能 (FLOPS) がFP32のときの2倍となる**ダブルレートのFP16**自体は、Voltaの前世代、Pascalアーキテクチャの**GP100**コアにて最初に実現されています。
具体的にはTesla P100やQuadro GP100が該当します。

- [NVIDIA Tesla P100 PCIe 16 GB Specs | TechPowerUp GPU Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/tesla-p100-pcie-16-gb.c2888) (GP100)
- [NVIDIA Quadro GP100 Specs | TechPowerUp GPU Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/quadro-gp100.c2994) (GP100)

ただし同じPascalアーキテクチャでも、GP102コアやGP104コアを採用するGPUではFP16の演算器を搭載せず、FP32の演算器を使ってエミュレートしているため、理論演算性能は逆にFP32のときよりも劣り、レートは1/64となります。これらは機械学習用途よりもゲーミング性能を重視した、Maxwellの改良に近い設計です。

- [NVIDIA TITAN X Pascal Specs | TechPowerUp GPU Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/titan-x-pascal.c2863) (GP102)
- [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti Specs | TechPowerUp GPU Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-1080-ti.c2877) (GP102)
- [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Specs | TechPowerUp GPU Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-1080.c2839) (GP104)

MaxwellアーキテクチャではほとんどのコアでFP16に対応しておらず、ハイエンドのGM200でも演算自体をサポートしていませんが、モバイル向けのTegra X1では例外的にダブルレートのFP16をサポートしています。

- [NVIDIA GeForce GTX TITAN X Specs | TechPowerUp GPU Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-titan-x.c2632) (GM200)
- [NVIDIA Tesla M40 Specs | TechPowerUp GPU Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/tesla-m40.c2771) (GM200)
- [NVIDIA Jetson TX1 GPU Specs | TechPowerUp GPU Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/jetson-tx1-gpu.c3230) (GM20B)

TuringアーキテクチャではTensorコアを搭載しないゲーミング用の下位製品でもFP16演算器を搭載していて、ダブルレートのFP16をサポートしています。

- [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Specs | TechPowerUp GPU Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-1650.c3366) (TU117)

AMDもVega (GCN 5th Gen) 以降でダブルレートのFP16をサポートするGPUを投入しています。

- [AMD Radeon RX Vega 64 Specs | TechPowerUp GPU Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-rx-vega-64.c2871) (Vega 10)

GPUがダブルレートのFP16をサポートするかどうかはスペックシートを確認してください。